# Hyperv/Windows10 - Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: exit status

Tags: windows, docker, hyper-v

On Windows 10 Pro with Hyper V driver, I receive `Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: exit status 1` during creation and when I try to start it manually every time. I'm new with docker, in fact I installed it yesterday and I can't get past the `docker-machine create` of the tutorial so please be explicit because I might not know what you are talking about.

My docker version :
Client:

```
Version: 18.03.1-ce   
API version: 1.37  
Go version: go1.9.5  
Git commit: 9ee9f40  
Built: Thu Apr 26 07:12:48 2018  
OS/Arch: windows/amd64  
Experimental: false  
Orchestrator: swarm
```

Server:

```
Engine:  
Version: 18.03.1-ce  
API version: 1.37 (minimum version 1.24)  
Go version: go1.9.5    
Git commit: 9ee9f40  
Built: Thu Apr 26 07:21:42 2018  
OS/Arch: windows/amd64  
Experimental: false
```

my docker info :

```
Containers: 10  
Running: 0  
Paused: 0  
Stopped: 10  
Images: 2  
Server Version: 18.03.1-ce  
Storage Driver: windowsfilter  
Windows:  
Logging Driver: json-file  
Plugins:  
Volume: local  
Network: ics l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent  
Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gelf json-file logentries splunk syslog  
Swarm: inactive  
Default Isolation: hyperv  
Kernel Version: 10.0 16299 (16299.15.amd64fre.rs3_release.170928-1534)  
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro  
OSType: windows  
Architecture: x86_64  
CPUs: 1  
Total Memory: 2GiB  
Name: DESKTOP-U7SE6KH  
ID: TOUR:L7CY:M43V:HORP:CKX6:HQ5G:CLHP:ER42:6S6C:S6OP:NSVV:TGHY  
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\Docker  
Debug Mode (client): false  
Debug Mode (server): true  
File Descriptors: -1  
Goroutines: 25  
System Time: 2018-05-04T11:37:15.7567871+02:00  
EventsListeners: 1  
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/  
Labels:  
Experimental: false  
Insecure Registries:  
127.0.0.0/8  
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

the debug of the `docker-machine start`: (translated from French)

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker-machine --debug start v3  
Docker Machine Version: 0.13.0, build 9ba6da9  
Found binary path at C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker-machine.exe  
Launching plugin server for driver hyperv  
Plugin server listening at address 127.0.0.1:50263  
() Calling .GetVersion   
Using API Version 1  
() Calling .SetConfigRaw  
() Calling .GetMachineName  
command=start machine=v3  
Starting "v3"...  
(v3) Calling .GetState  
(v3) DBG | [executing ==>] :   C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive ( Get-VM v3 ).state  
(v3) DBG | [stdout =====>] : Off  
(v3) DBG |  
(v3) DBG | [stderr =====>] :  
(v3) Calling .Start  
(v3) DBG | [executing ==>] :   C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive Start-VM v3  
(v3) DBG | [stdout =====>] :  
(v3) DBG | [stderr =====>] : Start-VM : failure to start 'v3'.  
(v3) DBG | Impossible to start VM v3, because a Hyper-v componant is not executing.  
(v3) DBG | failure to start 'v3'. (VM ID BB5B1FE8-F47C-41BD-81B0-B8123FBD8080)  
(v3) DBG | The VM manager service couldn't start VM v3, because a Hyper-v componant is not executing (VM ID BB5B1FE8-F47C-41BD-81B0-B8123FBD8080).  
(v3) DBG | At char Line:1 : 1  
(v3) DBG | + Start-VM v3  
(v3) DBG | + ~~~~~~~~~~~  
(v3) DBG | + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-VM], VirtualizationException  
(v3) DBG | + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperationFailed,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.StartVM  
(v3) DBG |  
(v3) DBG |  
exit status 1
```

What I did from the start :
Installing docker
Set up a new external network switch in Hyper-v
`docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch Switch v3`
=>

```
Running pre-create checks...  
Creating machine...  
(v3) Copying C:\Users\ellipsys.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso to C:\Users\ellipsys.docker\machine\machines\v3\boot2docker.iso...  
(v3) Creating SSH key...  
(v3) Creating VM...  
(v3) Using switch "Switch"  
(v3) Creating VHD  
(v3) Starting VM...  
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: exit status 1
docker-machine --debug start v3.
```

I think I should add why I'm trying to do this part, when I was doing this : 
`docker run hello-world`
I got this error:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: container a1dacfdb8be544a4584c9a03aa680ee38982dbef067db1fc21f7be81aa7d416f encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows system call: Aucun hyperviseur n’est présent sur ce système. (0xc0351000) extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"a1dacfdb8be544a4584c9a03aa680ee38982dbef067db1fc21f7be81aa7d416f","Owner":"docker","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\a1dacfdb8be544a4584c9a03aa680ee38982dbef067db1fc21f7be81aa7d416f","Layers":[{"ID":"fa6f4543-52e8-5fa3-af6f-762b139c0160","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\8bba33d957624223f3c683adf8f20a16a6432a2d567f49ca817ea3d39b4cb8c0"},{"ID":"730d2383-3dac-5641-9cde-cc3650406df7","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\a074f06eccff5c926d712f2d5cdeaaf1d66d821329fe55019a1f7f564356a1f8"},{"ID":"cea96136-c3b4-5e16-a047-315ccfc7b7b2","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\ae7e69257f999132eb86b8981eba21d3b5364e75cff2b3004d61d9f71c6d6666"},{"ID":"eefa106d-7a8f-59fa-bdcb-b2ee7389b7ae","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\017cfd53ff613080550c89a6b7eebef9311c4fe0537662e61add60091137c73d"}],"HostName":"a1dacfdb8be5","HvPartition":true,"EndpointList":["d4239da9-6e8c-4420-b92d-6ab25edf9b0b"],"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\ae7e69257f999132eb86b8981eba21d3b5364e75cff2b3004d61d9f71c6d6666\\UtilityVM"},"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}.
```

from one topic to another I got to where I am, trying to create a machine and getting it started. Don't know if it mean that my problem is else from what I think.

Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with your hyperviser (probably not docker). You can refer, https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2009/09/28/how-to-fix-hypervisor-not-running/

Comment: Thanks, I will check and see if it's this.

Comment: I found the problem, it was far simpler thant that. It's because i was trying to use a VM in a VM.